# React-native upload image to aws S3 via Expo ImagePicker

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo, aws-amplify

I want to upload a Photo to the S3 bucket, I current using the Expo and aws-amplify to approach this.

the code to fetch the local image is below:

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'expo';

ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: 'Images',
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [1, 1],
  base64: true
})
.then(image => dispatch(pickImageSuccess(image)))
.catch(err => dispatch(piclImageFail(err)));
```

After I get the image I upload the image to s3 bucket via `{ Storage } from 'aws-amplify'`

```
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';

const file = image.base64;
const imageName = image.uri.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
console.log(imageName);
const access = { level: "public", contentType: 'image/jepg' };
Storage.put(`${username}/${imageName}`, file, access)
  .then(succ => console.log(succ))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

After 
I uploaded the image, I tried to open the image in the S3 bucket. The image can not be opened properly, also I can not access the image publicly unless I mark the file public in the S3 bucket.

Comment: may be because of typo: `contentType: 'image/jepg'` , should be `image/jpeg`

Comment: @Cherniv Thank you, I noticed that, buy it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figure out what the problem is. The put() method from Storage requires a blob for the argument. Here is what I did to achieve this.

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'expo';
import mime from 'mime-types';
import { Storage } from 'aws-amplify';


const imageName = image.uri.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
const fileType = mime.lookup(image.uri);
const access = { level: "public", contentType: fileType, };
fetch(image.uri).then(response => {
  response.blob()
    .then(blob => {
      Storage.put(`${username}/${imageName}`, blob, access)
        .then(succ => console.log(succ))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
});
```

Comment: The package "mime-types" can not be used, because it import the Node standard library module "path".